# What happens after my Google business email expires?

Tags: web-services

After my Google business email expires (and I'm not paying to extend it), of course my @mydomain.com would disappear. But how about my email data, can I export it? Or it will automatically load into an ordinary @gmail.com?

And how about my registered accounts on other websites that I used the @mydomain.com email?

Comment: Interesting question but I think this is better suitable at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think it might be more suitable to ask Google ;-)

Comment: For discussion about whether this question is on-topic, please refer to this [meta question](http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/questions/188/are-questions-about-web-services-on-topic), and contribute your opinions.

Comment: <comments removed> @Mawg  Please review our [Be Nice policy](http://iot.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) about belittling language and name calling.

Answer (score 4):

Even though I think you get better answers at [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). I can give you some info.

> But how about my email data, can I export it?

As per [support docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6388094?hl=en), if your trial period ends, you will get a notification saying that your account is suspended **but** you can still access the Admin console and all your data is retained, but users won't have access to email, storage, and other services. People outside your domain can still access files that you shared with them.

This will be the same case even if your subscription ends.

> Or it will automatically load into an ordinary @gmail.com?

I don't think this happens automagically.

Comment: 1. Thanks for your answer. I had actually read the [google docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6388094?hl=en) but I just didn't think G Suite Trial is the same case to my subscription. Thanks for pointing that out.<br/> 2. I think google docs sometimes doesn't show all possibilities for every aspect of a google account <br/> 3. And how about my registered accounts on other websites that I used the @mydomain.com email? <br/> 4. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @ninjateam.org I'm not sure of it, I just thought it would be the same. You should check it with Google to confirm.